# Adding a small UIScrollView within a UIViewController

Tags: uiscrollview, swift3

I'm trying to create a UIScrollView that does not completely cover a UIViewController screen. See the screenshot below. I put in some segmented controls just for spacing and illustration purposes. I also shrunk the content view (green) just to show that it is within the scroll view (light blue). The scroll view is about half the screen and the content view is about 1,000 (an arbitrary height).

I did search all over and almost every tutorial shows a scroll view that completely covers the UIViewController.

I've tried for a few hours to get this working but I always run into a number of structural issues like ambiguity. Btw, I'm doing this in Swift 3 under Xcode 8.

Has anyone done this and if so, how were you able to do that?

Appreciate any response.

David

[Screenshot of Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1WN7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size ambiguity is not so much a "structural issue" of a scroll view with limited size, but rather the result of missing constraints. It is impossible to answer which ones you miss without knowing which ones you have defined and what exactly is ambiguous.

If your problem is that your scroll view does not scroll, the usual problem is that the views in you content are not fully defined in their vertical spaces and hence cannot define the height of their super view (your content view). That means you need vertical space constraints between as well as one top and one bottom constraint.

This is also mentioned in the third point in the Apple documentation:

> Here are some notes regarding Auto Layout support for UIScrollView:
>
> - In general, Auto Layout considers the top, left, bottom, and right edges of a view to be the visible edges. That is, if you pin a view to the left edge of its superview, you’re really pinning it to the minimum x-value of the superview’s bounds. Changing the bounds origin of the superview does not change the position of the view.
> - The UIScrollView class scrolls its content by changing the origin of its bounds. To make this work with Auto Layout, the top, left, bottom, and right edges within a scroll view now mean the edges of its content view.
> - The constraints on the subviews of the scroll view must result in a size to fill, which is then interpreted as the content size of the scroll view. (This should not be confused with the intrinsicContentSize method used for Auto Layout.) To size the scroll view’s frame with Auto Layout, constraints must either be explicit regarding the width and height of the scroll view, or the edges of the scroll view must be tied to views outside of its subtree.
> - Note that you can make a subview of the scroll view appear to float (not scroll) over the other scrolling content by creating constraints between the view and a view outside the scroll view’s subtree, such as the scroll view’s superview.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm kind of new to all this so I'll keep learning.